# SQL delete a lot of entries using a subquery

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have two database tables. One table is from WordPress (`wp_post`) containing all posts from my WordPress site. The second table is just for application logic and stores the IDs from the posts that were created using my plugin.

So there are about 70.000 IDs in my application logic table and I want to delete all posts using a single SQL statement. That's the statement I tried:

`DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE ID in (SELECT post_id FROM wp_my_table WHERE post_id IS NOT NULL AND post_id > 0);`

The subquery gets **ALL** IDs to delete, but my MySQL Server responds that the statement takes too much amount of time and cancels the execution of the statement. Is there a different way to get all IDs and delete all posts?

I know there are some WordPress functions like `wp_delete_post`etc. - but when deleting that amount of posts it's really, really slow.

Comment: Could add `LIMIT 1000` on the end of the select then simply repeat it and increase the limit size until you get through them all or hit time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a delete join:

```
DELETE t1
FROM wp_posts t1
INNER JOIN wp_my_table t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.post_id
WHERE
    t2.post_id > 0
```

You should not need the `NULL` check on the `post_id` in the `wp_my_table` table as the join should filter off such records.